# Varalakshmi Vratham

Tags: festivals, lakshmi, vrata

Today world is celebrating the Varalakshmi vratham. What is the significance of this? Has it been mentioned in devi bhagavatham? What is the procedure to perform this vratham? Also explain the benefits of performing the vratam.

Comment: I got the solution for my question as below--- This year Varalakshmi Vratham falls on Aug 12, 2016. On account of this auspicious occasion, we are glad to bring you two books: 1. Sri Varalakshmi Vratham Pooja Slokas and Mantras in Tamil
A complete set of slokas and mantras to do a proper pooja this Varalakshmi Vratham.
http://www.tamilbrahmins.com/showthread.php?t=28575

Comment: 2. Varalakshmi Vratham - Significance, How to, Slokas and Mantrams Varalakshmi Vratham Pooja is an important ritual performed by married women across South India for the welfare and prosperity of the family. http://www.tamilbrahmins.com/showthread.php?t=26903